# How to make an analogue of the chips component in ant design / or how to manage icons to achieve a similar result?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to make analogs of the chips component in ant design as in material ui
`https://material-ui.com/ru/components/chips/`, but I can't figure out how to set the position of the icons and add several icons
If ant design dont have the same component so how can I put several icons to the right side of the tag?

```
<Tag
      style={
        {
          width: '100px',
          borderRadius: '15px',
          backround: 'lightgrey',
          cursor: 'pointer',
          padding: '5px',
        }
      }
      icon={<DeleteOutlined
        className={'test'} />
      }>
      some text
    </Tag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the icons inside the Tag component like so:

```
<Tag
      style={
        {
          width: '100px',
          borderRadius: '15px',
          backround: 'lightgrey',
          cursor: 'pointer',
          padding: '5px',
        }
      }
>
      some text
      <CheckOutlined />
      <DeleteOutlined
        className={'test'} />
    </Tag>
```